how is it that i can choose .net 6 and 7 when it doesn't look like i have those fx installed
How is it that I can choose .Net 6 and 7 in the list in Visual Studio 2022 when it doesn't look like I have it installed?


I verified that the options in this Framework are related to .net-runtimes by creating asp.net core mvc app. I uninstall .net 3.1, please check the screenshot below.

The .Net 6 and 7 in Target Framework appears because you have installed the .Net 6/7 runtimes.
You can check it by using dotnet command below.
dotnet  --list-runtimes

I verified that the options in this Framework are related to .net-runtimes by creating asp.net core mvc app.
And you also can verify it in visual studio installer.

